# How can I recreate this diamond cut texture surface like on certain flashlights?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I was wondering if there was a way to recreate this sort of texture on a cylinder. 
I don't know if it's an actual texture or an actual surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding "I don't know if it's an actual texture or an actual surface", I don't think there is such a thing as an "actual texture". Textures are used to approximate details on a surface when modeling them manually would be impractical (e.g. modeling detailed 3D cracks and bumps into a model meant to be used in a real-time application, such as a game). Whether or not you use a 2D texture or 3D geometry to represent something is up to you and at what point you want to start using tricks to fake more detail.

Comment: It's called 'knurling', there are several tutorials if you google for 'blender knurling', e.g. https://blendabi.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/knurling/ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to do this :
Select the faces around your cylinder
[image: basic cylinder]
Add loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>mousewheel</kbd>) to make square faces
[image: cut cylinder]
In Object mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) add a decimate modifier on unsubdivide with 1 iteration and apply it
[image: decimate]
In Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) select your faces, then inset with <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> again for individual faces
[image: inset]
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while inseting to give some thickness or extrude individual faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
[image: extrude]
You're done!
[image: finished]

Comment: cool shortcut, is there also a way to scale it down along the x axis to get the diamond shape?

Comment: scaling the final object in Z should do, or playing with the base faces shape.

Comment: @Bithur when I select all the faces on the cylinder to inset it, it doesn't seem to inset just the faces itself rather it insets the whole cylinder. Is there a special way in doing this?

Comment: use "i" while in inset mode to use "individual faces"

Comment: @bither Perfect!

Answer (score 9):

You can do it both ways by model or faking the geometry by using a texture.

Starting with a plane extrude two edges so that you get a model like:

[image]

Add two *Array Modifiers* to create a grid:

[image]

Apply the modifiers and cut out the part you want to use, then scale it so that the tiles get the diamond shape. I've also selected the faces (by similar area) and beveled them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Add again an *Array modifier* and a *Curve modifier*:

[image]

Now you can decide to use it as geometry or bake it to a texture.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! Just one more question, how would I make those edges flat so it's not so pointy where it ends?

Comment: @WilliamTurner with a seam /\/\/\ selected press S-Z-0 then it will be flattened ------. Or use the knife tool K and cut the pointy ends away.

Comment: Oh ok sounds good, but could you go in a little more detail on the array modifier step? It seems like when I use it, it only repeats itself on one axis and gets longer when I add another one in the same direction.

Comment: @WilliamTurner you would need two array modifiers for two directions in the 2nd image you can see that there is another one. 1st with x offset and 2nd with y-offset.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence haha seems like I'm getting stuck at every step. Just past the array modifier step and I got stuck at the part where you state to cut out the part you want to use then scale it to get the diamond shape

Comment: @WilliamTurner Box select 'B' then invert the selection 'I' and 'X' to delete. (assuming modifier have been applied in object mode). It's probably a good idea to save the .blend just in case.

Comment: Almost there! I got up to the last step but I wanted to try the bevel in the previous step. So I selected the faces by similar faces and went to bevel it but it seems like it only bevels it on just two sides of the face and it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Ah and to note when I select a face it seems like the diamond face only has two selected edges when I do.

Comment: Ah I figured out how to fix it. All I did was extrude all those faces to create the other two edges I was missing.

Comment: Hm now it seems when I do bevel it all four sides kind of act like an inset and stay on the same plane and stay flat, rather than what the bevel tool is really suppose to do

Comment: Figured everything out haha, thanks for all your help. You the realest MVP! (: