# How do I model a cylinder with rotated diamond-shaped faces and bevel

Tags: modeling, faces, bevel

I would like to know how to rotate the faces of a cylinder while retaining the edge flow so that the square faces will be diamond shaped, I.E. rotated 45 degrees while remaining connected to the mesh.

I would then like to bevel the faces to achieve the effect as in the following picture, similar to a thumbscrew fastener with knurled sides.

[image: Cylinder with Rotated Beveled Faces]

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Check the thumbscrew section towards the end http://topologyguides.com/

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/how-can-i-recreate-this-diamond-cut-texture-surface-like-on-certain-flashlights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something very close to this without having some magic going on - starting with your cylinder with enough edge loops to get your desired face count, you select all the faces you need to work on and use alt-P to poke the faces. Once you do that, you select an edge running perpendicular and shift-G, choosing 'same length' and then X ,'dissolve edges'. Run the same thing going the other way except you may need to change to vertex select so you can deselect the edge loops at the end of the cylinder. Dissolve the horizontal loops and you are left with your diamond pattern, and it should still connect to the other part if you have left them connected.[image][image][image][image][image][image]