# How to extrude faces in the form of triangles depending on their position?

Tags: vertices, faces, extrude

I want to extrude **smooth convex triangles** like in this photo -

[image]

But I don't want to do it **manually,** besides they are not the same.

How can I do that?

Comment: hello, what do you mean by "manually"? without addon?

Comment: Not only, I can do that just "Poking" faces and drag every centered vertex, but how to apply that to many faces at once with "stretched" effect?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26794 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77027

Comment: Also useful examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UV Sphere, select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, in the *Operator* box choose *Iterations > 1*:

[image]

Cut the top:

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>i</kbd> twice to inset individual faces:

[image]

Scale up:

[image]

Transform a bit, give it a *Bevel* modifier:

[image]

Comment: No way! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I tested Poke Face, I don't think it is useful here, but if you ever need to select similar vertices/faces/edges, press Ctrl G (Select Similar) and check the options

Comment: Ok, thanks again