# Basketball net is not colliding with ball

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I have a simple model, a ball going through a basketball net. I want to have the mesh collide with the ball as it goes through but whatever settings I try I cant get the ball to collide with the mesh properly. I'm a newbie at Blender so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Similar question: [How can I keep those stripes together?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/276268/60486)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version will be very heavy for calculation because for such a stringy collision you will have to extremely increase "Quality Step" value in Cloth Sim. I would try simple cloth mesh baked and for your hires basket net use **Surface Deform** modifier with Target baked simple cloth.

### Basket

- add **Cylinder** (12 sides), add few horizontal **LoopCuts** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Un-SubDiv 1** switch squares to rhombus net ... shape it as you like
- select top vertices and Assign them to **Vertex Group** under Data Properties
- add **SubSurf** modifier > Simple

### Simulation

- add Physics Properties > **Cloth** > Shape > Pin Group
- Bake

[image]

From here you can use your hires basket if matches lowres model shape. For example here I just

- Duplicate lowres basket
- Delete Cloth Sim
- Delete <kbd>X</kbd> **Faces Only**
- add **Skin** modifier
- add **Surface Deform** modifier > Target lowres model with cloth simulation > Bind

[image]

Like now the lowres drives highres model animation and you can anytime go to lowres and run sim independently on hires model.

[image]

Notes:

- More details for diamond net [see this A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26828/2214)
- Cloth Properties - preset Denim, substeps 32, Vertex Mass 0,1 kg, Stiffness 30, Self-Collsion ON
- Skin modifier - select all vertices and from 3Dview properties panel (N) decrease **Mean Radius** to 0.05

Comment: Sorry, comments are not for conversation, can you write me PM on blenderartists and delete comments here? Thank you. You cant do sim without faces, you have to keep original (delete faces and skin is like final touch), that is why I want to use for hires model Mesh Deform modifier, that will animate hires by lowres (faced) model with Cloth sim.

Comment: I'm such idiot :) Surface Deform modifier works for that :) Will update answer.