# What would be the best way(s) to reproduce this ´wireframe mesh´ (see picture below) without having a ridiculous amount of vertices if possible?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I recently stumbled upon Vitaly Bulgarov's works and he did some mechs/robots with wireframes limbs (not sure about the name actually) like this one :

[image]

More references here in case you need : https://www.artstation.com/artwork/l46qz

I tried using combinations of Wireframe modifier + Subsurf modifier + bevel modifier, the problem is, with a simple small sized plane, you quickly reach 1 million vertices.

If you watch carefully, in the picture, the holes are not circular (which could be achieved by simply using the subsurf and doing inset > delete face so all holes are circles, though it also requires a lot of vertices), but here they are squary.

The biggest issue that I have is that the wireframe modifier gives very sharp/ugly geometry which I would like to avoid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26828/2214 you can try something like this for real geometry, but  as already mentioned I don't think he is using real geometry, it seems more like a shader. ... More of that if you check images on artstation. .. so why tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to stick with real geometry ... in this example:

- add cylinder, Loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Un-Subdivide = 1 (to get rhombus pattern)
- Bevel <kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Invert Selection <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Delete Faces

Modifiers

- Array Modifier
- Solidify Modifier > Complex
- Bevel Modifier > Width
- Curve Modifier

[image]

3000 vert for segment, 63000 vert for object

[image]

[image]

Sure in case of your example you would have to apply Array and there is nothing more you can save on poly-count. So if you are looking for something more lighter shader is your way.

Comment: That is perfect! No idea why I didn't think about using the solidifier, makes things way simpler! thanks for putting the file as well

Answer (score 1):

What about procedural texturing? I'd think this could be achieved quite quickly with a checkerboard texture node, a mix shader node, and a transparent shader node. When things are at that small scale, it's hard to notice small things like hole shape, so unless you are zooming in really close, I wouldn't worry about that.

[image]

I've just set something simple up here, but to fine tune your results, I'd use a brick texture.

[image]

Comment: I would like to avoid any rendering tricks but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you want to avoid the poly count you have to use transparency to punch holes in the mesh instead.